# org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key XXX must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key YYY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Having a following SQL table:

```
create table users_posts_ratings_map (
  postId integer not null references posts (id),
  userId integer not null references users (id),
  ratingId integer not null references ratings (id),
  primary key (postId, userId)
);
```

and Following JPA-Annotated POJOs:

RatingId.java:

```
@Embeddable
public class RatingId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId")
    private Post post;

    // getters and setters
}
```

UserPostRating.java:

```
@Entity(name = "users_posts_ratings_map")
public class UserPostRating {
    @EmbeddedId
    private RatingId userPost;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ratingId")
    private Rating rating;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Post.java

```
@Entity(name = "posts")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // irrelevant fields

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_posts_ratings_map",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ratingId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "postId"), @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }
    )
    private Set<UserPostRating> ratings = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

I am getting

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKB278E73083D94769:users_posts_ratings_map [postId,userId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (users_posts_ratings_map [ratingId,postId,userId])
```

on servlet container initialization stage.

What does it mean (What are Foreign Keys in this mappings? What are Primary Keys? Which annotations are marking what?) and how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This mapping doesn't make much sense. You have an entity `UserPostRating`, mapped to the `users_posts_ratings_map`, and having a `ManyToOne` association with the entity `Post`.

And in `Post`, you have a set of `UserPostRating`, but you map it as a second association, and make it a `ManyToMany`. It isn't a `ManyToMany`. It's a `OneToMany`, since the other side is a `ManyToOne`. And since the bidirectional association is already mapped in `UserPostRating`, you can't map it a second time in `Post`. So the code should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userPost.post")
private Set<UserPostRating> ratings = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

The Mapping is correct, since it is a many to many mapping so its mapping will result to new table. So you should not refer to existing entity table, rather you should provide any other name whose mapping/entity name does not exist.
Below is your example :

```
 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_posts_ratings_map",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ratingId") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "postId"), @JoinColumn(name = "userId") }
    )
    private Set<UserPostRating> ratings = new HashSet<>();
```

**Change the name from** `"users_posts_ratings_map"` to any other name like `users_posts_ratings_map1` or `users_posts_ratings_map_item`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message I suspect, that you have to move the definition of

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ratingId")
private Rating rating;
```

from the class `UserPostRating` to the class `RatingId`.